# read structure from binary file having pointer pointed to memory

Tags: c++, c, pointers, structure, fread

```
struct st {
        char *p;
        int len;
};
```

this is the structure which i need to write to a binary file, along with the string which is saved in

`char *p`

I am supposed to write a binary file with the char array data. After writing to binary file. Is should also be able to read it in the same structure from binary file.

I tried using FSEEK_END to get the binary size, and doing fread according to file size, but it is not saving string. Please suggest. Any help/suggestion/pointer would be appreciated.

thanks in advance.

sample code:

```
 struct st {
         char *p;
         int len; 
 };

 struct st varr;
 varr.len = 100;
 varr.p = new char[gen];
 strcpy(varr.p, "Hello World");

 FILE *p;
 p=fopen("address","wb");
 fwrite(&varr,sizeof(struct st),1,p);
 fclose(p);
```

this will write me the pointer to the binary file. But i want to write here whole string, but the point is, it should done with one fwrite.

Comment: Post the code you tried.  It's impossible to know what's wrong without seeing your code.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks for replying. Please check my code

Comment: If you want to write the data with one fwrite call you'll need to construct a buffer in memory with the data in a suitable format as described in the answers below. You need to write the string data, not the pointer, and you need to know the length, neither of which is possible in one fwrite call using that struct.

Comment: You should choose one language which for this code looks like C.

Comment: Thanks. c++ and c, both can fullfill my goal. hence thought of asking both experts

Comment: If you want a C++ answer then why are you using `fwrite` and `struct st varr;`?

Comment: using cstdlib header

Comment: You are writing pointer values to a file. This doesn't make sense. Read the chapter dealing with pointers in your C text book first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are so much concerned about not having two `fwrite` you can have wrapper structure with zero length array.

```
 struct st_wrap {
         int len; 
         char p[0];
 };

struct st_wrap *temp= malloc (sizeof (struct st_wrap ) + strlen(varr.p)+1);
temp->len = strlen(varr.p);

//Copy the data
strcpy(temp->p,varr.p);

//Then write it to file
fwrite(temp,sizeof(struct st_wrap)+strlen(varr.p),1,p);
```

Comment: It's your answer, so it's up to you to find a solution. It could be done with a similar trick as for the write part.

Answer (score 5):

There is no use writing this to a binary file. A text file would suffice.

However, if this is your homework assignment (or so), I suggest you proceed as follows:

- write the length as an integer;
- write `len` bytes of the string. This does not include a terminating null.

When reading back:

- read the integer length;
- allocate memory of this length *plus one byte*
- read the string into that memory and *add the terminating null*.

Fill your structure with this length and the pointer to allocated memory.

---

In your comments you keep iterating you want to read and write in one step. *With your current data structure that is not possible* because the character string wil always be somewhere else in memory and `fwrite` can only write a contiguous block of memory.

However, would you change your data structure to:

```
struct st{
    char p[128];
    int len;
};
```

then you *can* write and read in one go because now the struct is a contiguous memory block. But now the string is limited to this 128 bytes(or any size you make it).

Comment: thanks for your reply. Is there any way i can write in one step? and also read in one step. Because, 2-3 steps is costing me much for several files in a loop. If it can happen in one read and write will optimize my code.

Comment: Nonsense. "optimize my code". You are just lazy in typing? The above is the way to proceed.

Comment: @VishwadeepSingh You're asking *how* to do basic IO.  Don't worry about optimizing yet.

Comment: @AndrewHenle no, doing fwrite in one step is my goal, along with the string saved in char *

Comment: @VishwadeepSingh Do you even know how `fwrite()` works and how to optimize that?  Do you know how your filesystem works and how to optimize that?  Do you know how your disk controller(s) work and how to optimize the way you do IO to take advantage of their particular performance characteristics?  Do you know how your disk(s) themselves work?  And if you do, do you know how much faster your "optimized" IO would be?  **Write clear, understandable code.**  Don't worry about optimizing until you have a known performance problem to solve. Then if it's an IO problem, go buy a faster disk.

Comment: @VishwadeepSingh you cannot do this with a single `fwrite` and there are no "tricks". Do as suggested in this answer, it's the best you can do. Worry about optimisation later. That's the professional way of approaching things. If the structure was with `char p[MAXLENTH]` instead of `char *p`, then, and only then you can do a single `fwrite` and a single `fread`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest saving the strlen(p) first, followed by all the chars pointed by char *p. If you try to fwrite the struct as it is, you'll end up (in the file) with the value for the address with regrads to the first char. You do not want to save the address of the 1st char, do you?

Comment: no saving the address will not help. Hence i am finding a way to write the whole structure in a binary in one fwrite, with the string as well. Is there any way i can do

Comment: Change `char *` to `char []`?

Comment: i cannot change the structure

Comment: @VishwadeepSingh Then you have to have two `fwrite` .

Comment: there cannot be any other way? @kiranBiradar

Comment: Nope, mate:
a) fwrite(  fp, "%d", strlen(p) );
b) fputs(fp, p); or fwrite( fp, "%s", p );

Comment: @VishwadeepSingh Nope, you know the reason.

Comment: Thanks. I knew logically it is not possible. I thought any trick or something might be available.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have written the length and string to binary file:

```
FILE* fp = fopen("file.bin", "wb");

/* writing */
st str = { .p = "foo", .len = 3 };
fwrite((char*)(&str.len), sizeof(str.len), sizeof(str.len), fp);
fwrite(str.p, str.len, str.len, fp);
```

You can now (in a different context) read the content from file into the struct object:

```
FILE* fp = fopen("file.bin", "rb");
st str;
/* read length */
fread((char*)&str.len, sizeof(str.len), sizeof(str.len), fp);
/* allocate enough space */
str.p = malloc((str.len + 1) * sizeof(char));
/* read string */
fread(str.p, str.len + 1, str.len + 1, fp);
```

Remember to free memory when you're done with `p`:

```
free(str.p);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried lot of ways, but @kiran Biradar's answer helped me a lot. hence displaying the working code here.

WriteBinaryFile.cpp

```
    struct st_wrap {
            int len;
            int crc;
            char p[0]; 
    };


    int main ()
    {
            char p[100] = "Hello World";
            struct st_wrap *temp= (struct st_wrap*) malloc (sizeof (struct st_wrap ) + strlen(p)+1);
            temp->len = strlen(p);
            temp->crc = 400;
            strcpy(temp->p,p);
            cout << temp->p << endl;
            cout << temp->len << endl;
            cout << temp->crc << endl;

            FILE *p1;
            p1=fopen("binary.dat","wb");
            fwrite(temp,sizeof(struct st_wrap)+strlen(p),1,p1);
            fclose(p1);

    }
```

ReadBinaryFile.cpp

```
struct st_wrap {
        int len;
        int crc;
        char p[0];
};


int main ()
{
        struct st_wrap *vw;
        FILE *f=fopen("binary.dat","rb");
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
        long int filesize = ftell(f);
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
        vw = (struct st_wrap*) malloc (filesize);
        fread(vw,filesize,1,f);
        cout << vw->len << endl;
        cout << vw->p << endl;
        cout << vw->crc << endl;
        return 0;
}
```